# Insert Auto Increment INT Data in Table without Identity in which Starting value is some Integer

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, auto-increment

I have a table PurchaseInvoice in which there is collumn name "OurRef".In tabe i want to insert vale od OurRef initially 100.But If SupplierID Exist in PurchaseInvoice table i want to increase ourref Value By 1 each time for same SupplierID.Initially Ourref for First Entry Of SupplierID will be 100.Anf After second time insertion I want the Ourref 101.And It will go on.I have written Stored Procedure for that but It is not working.Thanks In Advance.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[addPurchaseInvoicing]
( @SupplierID int,
    @OurRef int,)
AS
DECLARE @ID INT = 0;
   BEGIN 
   IF EXISTS(select OurRef from tblPurchaseInvoice where SupplierID=@ID)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblPurchaseInvoice(OurRef)
    VALUES ( @OurRef+1);
    SET @ID = @@IDENTITY;
   END
   ELSE
   INSERT INTO tblPurchaseInvoice(OurRef)
    VALUES (100);
    SET @ID = @@IDENTITY;RETURN @ID
END
```

Comment: Not quite following you here. But you should use SCOPE_IDENTITY instead of @@IDENTITY. If you have a trigger on that table you will get incorrect values.

Comment: Is OurRef even an identity column?

Comment: Yes.I want to just insert value or Ourref in my table initially 100 for Fresh SupplierID which Comes with the Method I have defined in server side Coding.And Once one SupplierID will come the value of the Ourref to be inserted will be 100.After that for the same SupplierID for the Next Inseertion I want to be Ourref Column Increment by 1.So Ourref will be 101.And it will go so on that way.

Comment: No OurRef is not Identity Column.SupplierID is Identity Collumn.So For My reference I want the Number of How manny Supplier has Inserted The data in purchaseInvoice Table in my case.

Comment: Then maybe you could modify the code in my posted response to use count instead of just using +1

Comment: It sounds like you may get into all sorts of problems with concurrency here.

Comment: @Andrew is spot on. Concurrency can and will be an issue doing something like this at some point or another. And what about deletes? You will have gaps in this running number. Not sure what you are doing with but that might be an issue.

Comment: @SeanLange To increase the count for OurRef I have to Get the Maximum Value of the OurRef from the tblpurchaseInvoice.So If I got that Maximum Number Then in the condition we can Increase by 1.And If in the Select Query If OurRef is NULL then the value to be inserted will be 100.And Once Again OurRef is not the Identity OR Primary Key Column.SupplierID is the Identity Column.So i want the Number increment of OurRef For all the SupplierID.If New SupplierID Arise OurRef Will be 100.And FOr Existing we get the Max value of Ourref for perticular SupplierID and Increse OurRef value by 1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Notice I changed the EXISTS condition to check for @SupplierID instead of @ID (which would always be 0 in the code you posted).

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[addPurchaseInvoicing]
( 
    @SupplierID int
    , @OurRef int
)
AS

IF EXISTS(select OurRef from tblPurchaseInvoice where SupplierID = @SupplierID)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblPurchaseInvoice(OurRef)
        VALUES ( @OurRef + 1);
        SELECT @OurRef + 1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblPurchaseInvoice(OurRef)
        VALUES (100);
        SELECT 100
    END
```

Comment: For This Above Code I tried.But It is inserting Ourref Value 100 First Time.And After That It is inserting Ourref=1.And after inserting Second and third time it is inserting only 1 for OurRef column.

Comment: What is the value of @OurRef that you pass in? This is why I suggested that maybe you want to change this to use count(*) instead of a parameter.

Comment: Instead of SELECT @_OurRef + 1 try changing it to select count(*) + 101 
from tblPurchaseInvoice 
where SupplierID = @_SupplierID

Comment: Or maybe you need to change this to select max(OurRef) + 1? This is all guess work as I don't really know what you are trying to do here.